# How to automate historical key statistics from yahoo?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

With the code below, i'm able to get current key statistics from Yahoo for multiple tickers. Do you know  if it's possible to change the code below in order to get historical data ? For instance, the statistics registered for a ticker 3 years ago ?

Many thanks in advance for your answers and  you for your help

```
Sub KeyStat()

For i = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

ticker = Sheets(1).Cells(1, i)
qurl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "/key-statistics?p=" & ticker & ""

Sheets(2).Select
Sheets(2).Cells.Clear

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

Sheets(2).Range("B3:B69").Copy
Sheets(1).Select
Cells(2, i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
CutCopyMode = False

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `ticker`?

Comment: Works for me with a valid ticker symbol

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: The above code is useful but is limited to the use of 50 tickers. If I use more than 50 tickers, I am confronted with bugs. 
Is there a possibility to modify this code to load in mass the statistical data of several hundred tickers? Many thanks in advance for your help.